# nohup doesn't work in VSCode integrated terminal in Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, nohup, vscode-remote-ssh

I run scripts that take hours to complete in the background using `nohup`, so that they continue to run after I disconnect.  For example `nohup julia myscript.jl &> logfile.txt &`. This works fine when I'm connected to the compute server over plain ssh. But if I do this when connected using VSCode RemoteSSH extension, the julia process dies soon after I close VSCode.

How can I put a process in the background from VSCode RemoteSSH terminal, so that it keeps running in the background even after I close VSCode?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`julia myscript.jl &> logfile.txt & disown $!`

Many apps don't respect nohup, so you can use `disown` instead. The `$!` syntax is a special variable that represents PID of last executed command.